# LCD Blinking after inserting code : A medication reminder system using Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd, rtc

RTC DS3231,Arduino Uno and 4 push buttons, 10K potentiometer, 4 of 10K resistor and a buzzer. I decided to follow from an online source and encounters a few problems which already fixed but this one puzzles me. Would really appreciate your help. The RTClib.h library is already installed.LCD Blinking after inserting code and it shows blocks instead of characters.

There's other picture in this link too.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OzHqZlS7mnkngMx-EIiqIgzdHZaTsHr8

[image]

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <RTClib.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>

RTC_DS3231 rtc;

const int rs = 12, en = 11, d4 = 5, d5 = 4, d6 = 3, d7 = 2;                 // lcd pins
LiquidCrystal lcd(rs, en, d4, d5, d6, d7);

int buzz = 13;
int addr=17;

const int buttonPin2 = 9;
const int buttonPin3 = 8;
const int buttonPin1 = A0;
const int buttonPin4 = 7; // the pin that the pushbutton is attached to
int val2 = 0;
int val3=0;
int pushVal;
int bS1 = 0;         // current state of the button
int lBS1 = 0;     // previous state of the button


int bS2 = 0;         // current state of the button
int lBS2 = 0;

int bS3 = 0;         // current state of the button
int lBS3 = 0;

int bS4 = 0;         // current state of the button
int lBS4 = 0;

// configure the pins to the right mode
int buzz8amHH = 8;          //    HH - hours         ##Set these for reminder time in 24hr Format 
int buzz8amMM = 00;          //    MM - Minute
int buzz8amSS = 00;          //    SS - Seconds

int buzz2pmHH = 8;          //    HH - hours
int buzz2pmMM = 1;          //    MM - Minute
int buzz2pmSS = 00;          //    SS - Seconds

int buzz8pmHH = 8;          //    HH - hours
int buzz8pmMM = 2;          //    MM - Minute
int buzz8pmSS = 00;          //    SS - Seconds



int nowHr, nowMin, nowSec; 

void gwsMessege(){               // print get well soon messege
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Stay Healthy :)");     // Give some cheers
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("Get Well Soon :)");// wish 
}

void helpScreen() {              // function to display 1st screen in LCD
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Press Buttons");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("for Reminder...!");
 }

void timeScreen() {              // function to display Date and time in LCD screen
  DateTime now = rtc.now();             // take rtc time and print in display
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Time:");
    lcd.setCursor(6, 0);
    lcd.print(nowHr = now.hour(), DEC);
    lcd.print(":");
    lcd.print(nowMin = now.minute(), DEC);
    lcd.print(":");
    lcd.print(nowSec = now.second(), DEC);
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("Date: ");
    lcd.print(now.day(), DEC);
    lcd.print("/");
    lcd.print(now.month(), DEC);
    lcd.print("/");
    lcd.print(now.year(), DEC);
    delay(500);
}

void setup()
{
Wire.begin();
  rtc.adjust(DateTime(F(__DATE__), F(__TIME__)));            // uncomment this to set the current time and then comment in next upload when u set the time
  //rtc.adjust(DateTime(2019, 1, 10, 7, 59, 30));                // manual time set

  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Welcome To Our");                                      // print a messege at startup
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("Medicine Reminder");
  delay(1000);
  gwsMessege();
  delay(3000);
  helpScreen();
  delay(2000);
  timeScreen();
  delay(3000);
  lcd.clear();

  pinMode(buttonPin1, INPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin2, INPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin3, INPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin4, INPUT);
  pinMode(buzz, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void ValSet(){
  Serial.println(EEPROM.read(addr));
  val2 = EEPROM.read(addr);                         // read previosuly saved value of push button to start from where it was left previously
  switch (val2) {
    case 1:
      lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Reminder set ");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("for Once/day !");
      pushVal = 1;
      delay(500);
      break;
    case 2:
      lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Reminder set ");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("for Twice/day !");
      pushVal = 2;
      delay(500);
      break;
    case 3:
      lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Reminder set ");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("for Thrice/day !");
      pushVal = 3;
      delay(500);
      break;
  }
}

// the main loop will constantly check to see if the button has been pressed
// if it has, a counter is incremented, and then some action can be taken
void loop() 
{                                         //call to set thrice/day 
    if (pushVal == 1) {                                // if push button 1 pressed then remind at 8am
    at8am();                                           //function to start uzzing at 8am 
  }
  else if (pushVal == 2) {                             // if push button 2 pressed then remind at 8am and 8pm
    at8am();                                            
    at8pm();                                           //function to start uzzing at 8mm
  }
  else if (pushVal == 3) {                             // if push button 3 pressed then remind at 8am and 8pm
    at8am();
    at2pm();                                            //function to start uzzing at 8mm
    at8pm();
  }
  // read the state of the button
  bS1 = digitalRead(buttonPin1);
  bS2 = digitalRead(buttonPin2);
  bS3 = digitalRead(buttonPin3);
  bS4 = digitalRead(buttonPin4);

  // check to see if it different than the last time we checked


if (bS2 != lBS2) {
    // either the button was just pressed or just released
    if (bS2 == HIGH) {
      // it was just pressed
      Serial.println("n02");
      EEPROM.write(17,1);
      push1();
      delay(1000);
    }
  }
  lBS2 = bS2;


if (bS3 != lBS3) {
    // either the button was just pressed or just released
    if (bS3 == HIGH) {
      // it was just pressed
      Serial.println("no3");
      EEPROM.write(17,2);
      push2();
      delay(1000);
    }
  }
  lBS3 = bS3;


if (bS4 != lBS4) {
    // either the button was just pressed or just released
    if (bS4 == HIGH) {
      // it was just pressed
      Serial.println("no4");
      EEPROM.write(17,3);
      push3();
      delay(1000);
    }
  }
  lBS4 = bS4;

if (bS1 != lBS1) {
    // either the button was just pressed or just released
    if (bS1 == HIGH) {
      val3=EEPROM.read(addr);
      EEPROM.write(17,0);
      digitalWrite(buzz, LOW);
      pinstop();
      EEPROM.write(17,val3);
    }
  }
  lBS1 = bS1;

  timeScreen();
  ValSet();
}
void push1() {                   // function to set reminder once/day                                           //save the state of push button-1 
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Reminder set ");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("for Once/day !");
    delay(1200);
    lcd.clear();
  }

void push2() {                      //function to set reminder twice/day
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Reminder set ");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("for Twice/day !");
    delay(1200);
    lcd.clear();
  }

void push3() {                    //function to set reminder thrice/day
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Reminder set ");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("for Thrice/day !");
    delay(1200);
    lcd.clear();
  }

void pinstop(){                   //function to stop buzzing when user pushes stop push button
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Take Medicine  ");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("with Warm Water");
    delay(5000);
    lcd.clear();
  }
void at8am() {                      // function to start buzzing at 8am
  DateTime t = rtc.now();
  if (int(t.hour()) == buzz8amHH && int(t.minute()) == buzz8amMM  && (int(t.second()) == buzz8amSS || int(t.second()) < buzz8amSS+10)) {
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        digitalWrite(buzz,HIGH);
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print("Time to take ");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print("Morning medicines.");
        delay(5000);

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      }
}

void at2pm() {                          // function to start buzzing at 2pm
  DateTime t = rtc.now();
  if (int(t.hour()) == buzz2pmHH && int(t.minute()) == buzz2pmMM  && (int(t.second()) == buzz2pmSS || int(t.second()) < buzz2pmSS+10)) {
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        digitalWrite(buzz,HIGH);
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print("Time to take ");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print("Afternoon medicines.");
        delay(5000);

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      }
}

void at8pm() {                           // function to start buzzing at 8pm
DateTime t = rtc.now();
  if (int(t.hour()) == buzz8pmHH && int(t.minute()) == buzz8pmMM  && (int(t.second()) == buzz8pmSS || int(t.second()) < buzz8pmSS+10)) {
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        digitalWrite(buzz,HIGH);
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print("Time to take ");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print("Night medicines.");
        delay(5000);

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      }
}
```

Comment: `encounters a few problems which already fixed but this one puzzles me` so which problem exactly? This sketch and the complexilty of the project is huge. You should provide a minimal example of what exactly is broken with which component, then people can help you better.

Comment: the lcd and the connection to the 4 push button and is my wiring correct ?

Answer (score 1):

Some troubleshooting ideas:

**1**. does turning the potentiometer change the brightness of the LCD?

A. If not, there is a (1) power problem (2) wiring problem.

**2**. Do you ever get strange characters on the LCD or just the "shows blocks instead of characters"?

A. If you only get the blocks.  THe data is probably not making it to the LCD.  THe LCD will display blocks by default.

B. If you get strange character data too, then data lines probably are't wired properly.

**3**. Upload a program which only does the following:

A. Initializes the LCD

B. prints one line of output every time in the loop()  This is the easiest way to determine if it is your wiring.  If you don't see anything on the LCD then there is a high probability you have a wiring problem.
This is also very easy to try because you just open up a new sketch, create it and upload it to your device.

**LCD Example**

Try this [official Arduino LCD Example](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/HelloWorld?from=Tutorial.LiquidCrystal) (just make sure your data lines match -- you can change the values in the sample code so they are appropriate for your situation.

If it is a wiring problem I'd start looking at

1. if you are getting the needed amount of current / voltage to the LCD
2. is each data line connected properly.  Unhook power and use a meter to check continuity from your Arduino to your LCD pins.

Answer (score 0):

Your wiring image is difficult to see. I recommend checking one by one.

Firstly, you connect Arduino with LCD only, make it work first. And then try the next.

I took at a glance at your code. There are some points you should check or change:

1. DO NOT use delay() function, if you uses delay() function, many pressing events will be missed. You should use timestamps instead. I recommend using [ezButton library](https://github.com/ArduinoGetStarted/button) to avoid the blocking or implement timestamp by yourself (refer to [BlinkWithoutDelay](https://arduinogetstarted.com/tutorials/arduino-led-blink-without-delay) example).
2. Seemingly, you are using the external pull-up/pull-down for buttons. I recommend using the internal pull-up to reduce the complexity of wiring.

For LCD, please refer to [this tutorial](https://arduinogetstarted.com/tutorials/arduino-lcd)